# Fresh Ubuntu 14.04. No Wireless rtl8723ae show disabled

Tags: wireless, networking, network-manager, ubuntu-drivers

First of all, thank you very much for any help. I am stumped.

I installed all the linux-headers I think I need. But make still fails for the driver. But it looks like the driver is available for rtl8623ae. It just show disabled.

```
sudo lshw -C network -numeric

*-network               
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: AR8161 Gigabit Ethernet [1969:1091]
       vendor: Qualcomm Atheros [1969]
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       logical name: eth0
       version: 10
       serial: 00:8c:fa:2b:0b:b3
       size: 1Gbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm pciexpress msi msix bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=alx duplex=full ip=10.0.0.22 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=1Gbit/s
       resources: irq:45 memory:c8500000-c853ffff ioport:3000(size=128)
  *-network DISABLED
       description: Wireless interface
       product: RTL8723AE PCIe Wireless Network Adapter [10EC:8723]
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. [10EC]
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       logical name: wlan0
       version: 00
       serial: 24:ec:99:fe:93:4c
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rtl8723ae driverversion=3.13.0-40-generic firmware=N/A latency=0 link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11bgn
       resources: irq:17 ioport:2000(size=256) memory:c8400000-c8403fff
```

Linux headers I installed.

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential libssl-dev linux-headers-`uname -r` linux-firmware-nonfree
```

I also followed instruction to remove my network manager and install wicd network manager.

```
sudo apt-get install wicd wicd-gtk wicd-daemon wicd-cli wicd-curses
```

Doesn't work either. Any help would really be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu 14.04 comes with a working rtl8723ae driver, so there is no need to build one.  Try the function key (F12 on my Toshiba) to enable/disable wireless.  Thats the "hard block" problem from the output of

```
rfkill list
```

The soft block problem is a program like NetworkManager not haveing the "Enable Wifi" checked.
Wicd works, but I don't have any experience with it.  Network Manager works for me.